# ARM assembly language adding register problem

Tags: assembly, arm

im haveing probelm with echoing a return value for adding registers and not really sure why this is happening. I'm very new to ARM assembly language and am attempting to tackle a lab but cant get past this basic problem.

code:

```
 .cpu cortex-a53
 .fpu.neon-fp-armv8

 .text

 .global _start

 _start:
   MOV R0, #1
   MOV R1, #3
   ADD R7, R0 , R1
   SWI 0
```

'''

When i execute the file and echo i end up getting an illegal instruction error and 132 returned to the screen. If anyone can help that would be appreciated

Comment: Which instruction is the illegal instruction? What operating system are you using?

Comment: @RaymondChen its not telling me it just claims a instructions is illigal but still returns a value of 132. im on a raseberry pi os

Comment: Use `strace`, or use a debugger to single step your code.  Are you sure `__NR_exit` is `4` on ARM, assuming this is Linux?  If not, then execution will continue past the `swi` into whatever garbage is next.

Comment: Call 4 seems to be `write` https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=arm_thumb for thumb. Not sure if this is thumb or aarch32 or aarch64.

Comment: Basically what we're saying is that the problem is not with the add. It's with what comes after it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: It's not AArch64; that uses register names of `x0` (64-bit) or `w0` for the 32-bit sub-register.  32-bit ARM mode uses the same call numbers as thumb mode, it seems (unsurprisingly since both modes can easily use the same low registers).  https://godbolt.org/z/MqiBsd shows that __NR_exit is 1 with Linux ARM gcc8.2 `-marm`.  So yeah, this code just falls off the end of _start